# How to change order of the columns after breakpoint?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have 3 columns in one row. After screen width reach less than md (768px) there is a breakpoint.
At this point, I want the first container become the last one and the two others stay in one line. How I can do it?

**Code:**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "After screen width reach md (768px)" do you mean less than or more, wider or narrower than 768? Please update the question so say "After screen width is [WIDER? OR LESS?] than md (768px)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the order classes...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 border order-last order-md-0">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-6 border">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-6 border">
        3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/fWWT94ZqXa)